# TableView with Image SubView performance Issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Ive got one question about using a subView in my custom TableViewCells. On certain rows i want to one or more images, and i am doing this programmatically with:

```
func addImageToCell(image: UIImage, initialYCoordinate: CGFloat, initialHeight: CGFloat, initialXCoordinate: CGFloat,imageUUID: String) {
    imageButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as? UIButton
    .....
    imageButton!.addTarget(formVC, action: "imageButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.contentView.addSubview(imageButton!)
}
```

That works fine. But, when i scroll my TableView and it comes to an row with an Image, there is a small "lag". Normally it is totally smooth, but when he is trying to load this cell, there is a (maybe 0,1 seconds) lag in the software.

Is there a better way to do this programmatically without any lags? Ill load my Images on initializing the UITableViewController from a CoreData Fetch.

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if(cellObject.hasImages == true) {

  cell.qIndex = indexPath.row

  var initialXCoordinate:CGFloat = 344.0

  let questionImages = formImages[cellObject.qIndex] as [String: Images]!

  for (key,image) in questionImages {

       let thumbnailImage = UIImage(data: image.image)

       cell.addImageToCell(thumbnailImage, initialYCoordinate: 44.00 ,initialHeight: cellObject.rowheight + cellObject.noticeHeight!, initialXCoordinate: initialXCoordinate, imageUUID: image.imageUUID)

       initialXCoordinate += 130
  }

}
```

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance

Edit: Ill use this to prevent the Buttons to get reused:

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {

    super.prepareForReuse()

    if(self.reuseIdentifier != "CraftInit") {

        for item in self.contentView.subviews {

            if(item.isKindOfClass(UIButton)) {

                item.removeFromSuperview()

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lag is most probably caused by the allocation of new memory for UIButton, adding it to cell's contentView and loading an image into it at the time of the cell being reused. That's one problem.
The other problem is that you're creating a button per every reuse of the cell. Basically, every time you scroll the cell out of the visibility range and scroll it back - you add another button with another image, that also consumes memory and performance.

To make this work properly you need to create a custom table view cell with a maximum amount of images (buttons) pre-rendered and hide the ones you don't need to show.

Do not add / remove subviews while reusing the table view cell, hide and show them instead, it's much faster.

Comment: Thanks. That was a way i am doing it long time ago. But: I have about 7 different Layouts for Cells (this is a complex form with about 100 Questions) - and i could add notices and images to each cell dynamically. If i create a notice for example (this is also a UIButton with text) there is no lag. Only for the images. But if this is the only way to handle that without loosing performance i would do that.

Comment: So you mean that i should in "prepareForReuse" only hide and show the Buttons, not deleting it from my Cell subView?

Comment: Adding or removing subviews while reusing a tableview cell will result in a big loss of performance. It might work fast on the iPhone simulator or your newest iPhone 6 Plus handheld but it will work slow on older devices. I'm not exactly sure about the layout and vertical constraints of your cells so it's quite hard to say how exactly you should build them. Creating a xib + different reuse identifier per each cell layout (even if you have 8 of them) would be a good first step, at least see if hiding/showing subviews rather than adding/removing them has any positive impact on your performance.

Comment: I have already 7 different Layouts (all with different ReUseIdentifiers) - i will try to hide/show instead of removing it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you removing these subviews? Because if you're not removing them, as the user scroll, you'll keep on adding subviews to the same cell over and over again, degrading performance.

My approach usually is to to have such views constructed when the cell is created rather than in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but I'm guessing you can't do that as you don't know the number of images. That said, you could still formulate a strategy where these subviews are added at cell creation, and then reused as per your model.

Another suggestion is to have the `UIImage` objects created all at once, outside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The Count of images is very dynamic - so i am able to create new images at runtime. Ill save the images in Core Data (one with full size and one small thumbnail, to prevent time loss on shrinking) - do you think when i create the image and save the images in an UIImage Array could boost the performance? That would be easy (i guess i should try that)